# getting alignment issue while zoom in zoom out where button position getting moved

Tags: html, css

i have a form page and it contains few drop-downs, upload and input text fields(for demo i am showing only few elements). i have a change mode button after the attack type dropdown its functionality is not mentioned but while zooming in zoom out that change mode button not maintaining alignment with other elements.

I tried with margin-left in pixes, percentile, and position: absolute, fixed but not working
Please help me with this issue.

**This is My HTML Code:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      label {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 30px;
        width: 22%;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 5px;
      }

      #attackType {
        width: 158px;
        border: none;
        height: 30px;
        background-color: #A9A9A9BF;
        border-radius: 2px;
      }

      #changeCustomPcapModeDiv {
        margin-left: 550px;
        height: 29px;
        margin-top: -29px;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background-color: #A9A9A9BF;
      }

      #customPcap {
        width: 200px !important;
      }

      .error {
        color: red;
      }

      #attackConfigBtn,
      #cancelBtn {
        width: 80px;
        height: 30px;
        padding-top: 4px;
        border: none;
        background-color: #A9A9A9BF;
        border-radius: 3px;
      }

      #attackConfigBtn {
        margin-left: 25%;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

      #cancelBtn {
        width: 70px;
        margin-left: 3%;
        font-family: Helvetica;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Attack Type:</label>
      <select name="attackType" id="attackType">
        <option value="attack_list">Attack List</option>
        <option value="custom_pcap">Custom PCAP</option>
      </select>
      <button id="changeCustomPcapModeDiv" style="display: block;">Change Mode</button>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top: 10px; display: block;" id="customDiv">
      <label>Custom PCAP Uplaod: </label>
      <input type="file" name="customPcap" id="customPcap" accept=".pcap" data-max-size="102400"><span id="customPcapErr" class="error" style="margin-left:35px;font-size:14px;"></span>
    </div>

    <input id="attackConfigBtn" type="button" value="Apply" title="Apply new configuration">
    <button id="cancelBtn" onclick="window.location = 'index.php'" title="Ignore configurations changes">Cancel</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

and these are the images of my Sample page:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please help me since i am new to HTML

Thanks

Comment: ` margin-left: 5SS50px;` a typo?

Comment: @gp. bro while adding in the stack over flow i write like that and now corrected but the issue was not fixed.

Comment: how u want your 'change mode' button to be align eventually ? (1) always next to `<select>` element ? (2) same row with `<select>` element but always floating to right ?

Comment: @Zeikman change button should next to the Attack Type Dropdown bro like in the first image.

Comment: ok, it is the CSS that causing the issue. I remove `margin-left: 550px` from class `.changeCustomPcapModeDiv` and also remove `display: block` from button `id="changeCustomPcapModeDiv"`, it should result in what you desired, give it a try. Let me know if u wish to have a visual sample.